# Parse query include only sub-sub object without including its parent

Tags: parse-platform

Imagine a relation like :
**Obj1** has a pointer to **Obj2** has a pointer to **Obj3**.

In a query of Obj1 i would like to include Obj3 WITHOUT including Obj2. 
I should be able to do this using dot notation in the include like:

```
query.include(["post.author"]);
```

My question is: 
Is this posible? 
Or Obj2 need/will be included anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Obj2` will be included because you need it to properly represent the relationships.

If you want to take it out then you need to deal with the relationships / containerisation yourself and the only way to do that would be to create a cloud function which collects the required objects and then packs them into a response object however you want them.

Comment: Just to clarify, my objective was to locally store the included Obj3 (pin the queue) so i can query them later on from local datastore. Even when the Obj2 could seem mandatory to retrieve the relation, it is not needed when you are not interested in the relation itself but just in the Obj3. Maybe it is not the most common scenario, but could be useful sometimes. I will just add a pointer to Obj3 inside Obj1. Thanks.